# Symfony3+PHPUnit. How to disable debug log in console?

Tags: symfony, logging, phpunit, monolog

I think I turned off debug logging everywhere (in config.yml, config_dev, config_test):

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: [!event]
    console:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/console.log"
        level: critical
        channels: [!event]
```

but when I run phpunit it shows me debug log:

```
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DebugHandlersListener::configure"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\DumpListener::configure"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\TestSessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\SessionListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\RouterListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
[2016-06-19 16:53:29] event.DEBUG: Notified event "{event}" to listener "{listener}". {"event":"kernel.request","listener":"AppBundle\\EventListener\\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest"} []
```

How to disable it?

Comment: What environment do you face the issue on?

Comment: I run phpunit, so i suppose it is test env.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you try this:

```
  console:
     type: stream
     path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/console.log"
     level: critical
     channels: []
```

Then it should be fine. I also had some issues with that, i just commented it out for my needs.
If you still want some debugging for doctrine, just put !doctrine in the brackets.
If i get you right, thats what you need.

Comment: Happy i could help dude!

Answer (score 3):

Test environment seems to run in debug mode which is enabled in the application kernel `$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);` in app_dev.php. Same goes for production evironment with one exception: the second argument should be false, which means that debug mode is disabled.

To get rid of the debug output in the test environment you need to pass the `--no-debug` flag to your command, example:
`php bin/console some:command --env=test --no-debug`

For PHPUnit it will not work. You may need to override the kernel of your application for `dev` environment:

Example from [Kris Wallsmith](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/27979797907/get-fast-an-easy-symfony2-phpunit-optimization) blog:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    // ...

    protected function initializeContainer()
    {
        static $first = true;

        if ('test' !== $this->getEnvironment()) {
            parent::initializeContainer();
            return;
        }

        $debug = $this->debug;

        if (!$first) {
            // disable debug mode on all but the first initialization
            $this->debug = false;
        }

        // will not work with --process-isolation
        $first = false;

        try {
            parent::initializeContainer();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->debug = $debug;
            throw $e;
        }

        $this->debug = $debug;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not help. 
The command I run - "phpunit", it does not belong to symfony. So it has no such options as `--env` and `--no-debug`.
But that debug log somehow goes from Symfony >.<

Full output:
http://pastebin.com/3BMUYuqs

Comment: Good catch. I think you might need to modify your application kernel /for the `dev` environment/. For an example follow this URL: http://kriswallsmith.net/post/27979797907/get-fast-an-easy-symfony2-phpunit-optimization.

Comment: rather than the cli flags do the environment vars `SYMFONY_ENV` and `SYMFONY_DEBUG` work?

Comment: this is just great, I was so tired of the event debug messages and did not want to to touch the dev config. this does exactly what I need.